# How do I create a sliding side navbar that dims the rest of the website when open?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I have a website and I have the layout in a way I want it to and I need to make a side navbar that slides open while dimming the rest of the page. but when I put my code together it only dims certain parts of my website instead of the whole thing. what am I doing wrong?

So basically I have a website and I have the layout in a way I want it to and I need to make a side navbar that slides open while dimming the rest of the page. but when I put my code together it only dims certain page of my website instead of the whole thing. what am I doing wrong?

here is the website https://thimbleprojects.org/wjtw9802/678158

HTML

```html
<html>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <div id="main">
      <body id="myDiv">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <div class="header" id="myDiv2">
          <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
          <h1>My Website</h1>
          <p style="text-align: right;">Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="leftcolumn">
            <div class="card" id="myDiv">
              <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
              <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
              <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
              <p>Some text..</p>
              <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <h2>Footer</h2>
        </div>

      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #565656;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #565656
}

.header p {
  color: #565656
}

.leftcolumn {   
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #d7cec7;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

.body {
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: `certain page of my website` ... please explain what this means? did you mean a certain part?

Comment: Could you possibly add a couple of screenshots showing the effects you describe?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes my bad there

Comment: Changing  the id your div with a class of "card" from "myDiv" to something unique (ex "myDiv4) and then adding  `document.getElementById("myDiv4").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4";` to your openNav function, definitely works to change the pink background to grey. However, you still have to make similar changes to your footer area. Also, you must make sure it changes back to the correct color in your closeNav function. For my example, add `document.getElementById("myDiv4").style.backgroundColor = "#d7cec7";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are solely affecting the background color of the main body tag on which are overlaid all you're other components.

The best way to proceed would be to add another div outside of your `main` div. Let's call it `overlay` that container will sit on top of all the other ones giving you the dim effect.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#overlay {
  margin-left:250px;
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #565656;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #565656
}

.header p {
  color: #565656
}

.leftcolumn {   
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #d7cec7;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

.body {
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
JAVASCRIPT
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <body id="myDiv">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <div class="header" id="myDiv2">
          <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
          <h1>My Website</h1>
          <p style="text-align: right;">Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="leftcolumn">
            <div class="card" id="myDiv">
              <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
              <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
              <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
              <p>Some text..</p>
              <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
          <h2>Footer</h2>
        </div>

      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 You could even add a `transition` to the overlay for looks! The only thing that bugs me is the menu area that is not affected by the overlay, which is visible until the menu fully expands. Perhaps a `z-index` solution?